# Issue with stored procedure, field or property not found?

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, boundfield

I'm trying to inner join `asp_Users` & `asp_Membership` tables so that i can retrieve the `CreateDate` field from `asp_Membership` in a `BoundField` of a `GridView` i have.

I have tried the following which seems to make sense to me but it keeps throwing the error:

`A field or property with the name 'CreateDate' was not found on the selected data source.`

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_Customer_Fetch_Paged]
    (
        @sortExpression nvarchar(100),
        @startRowIndex int,
        @maximumRows int
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Make sure a @sortExpression is specified
        IF LEN(@sortExpression) = 0 
            SET @sortExpression = 'aspnet_Users.UserId'

        -- Issue query
        DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
        SET @sql = '
        SELECT userid, username, first_name, last_name, town,postcode, rowrank FROM (
    SELECT     aspnet_Users.UserId, aspnet_Membership.UserId as MembershipID, aspnet_Membership.CreateDate, aspnet_Users.UserName, Customer.title, Customer.first_name, Customer.last_name, Customer.telephone, 
                          Customer.dpa_consent, Customer.billing_address_id, Address.friendly_name, Address.address_line_1, Address.address_line_2, 
                          Address.address_line_3, Address.town, Address.postcode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @sortExpression + ' ) AS RowRank
    FROM  Customer INNER JOIN
                          aspnet_Users ON Customer.userid = aspnet_Users.UserId 
                          INNER JOIN
                          Address ON Customer.billing_address_id = Address.address_id AND Customer.userid = Address.user_id
                          INNER JOIN
                          aspnet_Membership ON
                          aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId

        ) AS ProductsWithRowNumbers
        WHERE RowRank > ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex) + 
        ' AND RowRank <= (' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @startRowIndex)+ ' +  ' +
        CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @maximumRows) + ')'

        print @sql

        -- Execute the SQL query
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql

    END
```

Despite me selecting it in the stored procedure. I'm very new to SQL so it might be something simple i've overlooked? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your outermost `SELECT` clause doesn't include that column:

```
SELECT userid, username, first_name, last_name, town,postcode, rowrank
```

needs to be

```
SELECT userid, username, first_name, last_name, town,postcode, CreateDate, rowrank
```